# Determining the Newline character for the environment a C++ program is being compiled on

Tags: c++, newline

How does one determine the environment newline<sup>1</sup> in C++? Google yields many results for C# and .NET but I didn't see any way to do it for non-CLI C++.

Additional info: I need to scan a `const char*` for the character(s).

<sup>1</sup>By "environment newline" I mean `\r\n` on Windows, `\n` on Linux, and `\r` on Mac.

Comment: Why is outputting the "local" newline even necessary?  I wish people would stop polluting the world with the impression that "\r\n" is a newline on windows.  Just about every single text editor on windows handles "\n" just find.  The only counter-example I've ever heard of is Notepad!

Comment: This question made me spawn another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865398/inserting-endline-into-a-stringstream

Comment: @Andre who said anything about outputting?

Comment: @André: I've always wondered why Notepad thinks it's a typewriter. In this day and age, there is just no use for the carriage return character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>`std::endl` inserts a newline appropriate for the system. You can use a `ostringstream` to determine the newline sequence as a string at runtime.</strike>

```
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::endl;
    std::string thisIsEnvironmentNewline = oss.str();
}
```

**EDIT**: * See comments below on why this probably won't work.

---

If you know that your platforms will be limited to Windows, Mac, and Unix, then you can use predefined compiler macros ([listed here](http://predef.sourceforge.net/)) to determine the endline sequence at compile-time:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    #define NEWLINE "\r\n"
#elif defined macintosh // OS 9
    #define NEWLINE "\r"
#else
    #define NEWLINE "\n" // Mac OS X uses \n
#endif
```

Most non-Windows and non-Apple platforms are some kind of Unix variant that uses `\n`, so the above macros should work on many platforms. Alas, I don't know of any portable way to determine the endline sequence at compile time for all possible platforms.

Comment: Is this the only way to do it? I'd prefer to do it at compile time.

Comment: @Seth: why do you need to know the type of line break at compile-time?

Comment: @Remy because it requires no computation at run time :) I'll probably have to settle for this though.

Comment: @Seth: You'd only need to compute the line break sequence once. That computation would take probably less than a microsecond.

Comment: @Emile, I'm pretty sure that will always return '\n'. The conversion of '\n' to binary is handled by the underlying FILE stream. String streams should not be converting any characters outside of the bounded locale.

Comment: -1 for encouraging `std::endl`. Your first sentence should read "`'\n'` inserts a newline appropriate for the system." Regardless of how the newline sequence is recorded on disk, if you send `'\n'` to a stream, it will insert the system-appropriate end-of-line sequence. `std::cout << std::endl` is nothing more or less than `std::cout << '\n' << std::flush`.

Comment: @MSN: I didn't know the conversion was limited to file streams. I don't have a way to test my code on a non-Unix platform at the moment.

Comment: I guess I also forgot to mention that I am opening it in `ios::binary` mode because it could be either.

Comment: @Rob: Looks like I had misconceptions about `std::endl`.

Answer (score 4):

For formatted text IO in C++ (and C), the new line character is always `'\n'`. If you want to know the binary representation of a new line for a given platform and file mode, open a file in the desired mode (e.g., text or binary, UTF-8, UTF-16, MCBS, etc.), write out `'\n'`, close it, reopen it in binary, read in the entire file, and figure out what the actual binary encoding of `'\n'`. You may also have to account for the `end-of-file` character as well.

Comment: This works for systems with stream-oriented files (like Unix, DOS, and Windows), but not for record-oriented files (like on VMS). For some systems, the end-of-line indication is not stored as a character sequence at all.

Comment: @Rob, sure, but who uses VMS anymore? :) (j/k)

Comment: More seriously, does the _question_ even make sense in VMS?

Answer (score 1):

Generally with a #define. But, for simple applications, opening a file in "text mode" will give you what you need.