# Inserting endline into a stringstream

Tags: c++, newline, stringstream, end-of-line

We know that when inserting `\n` in a file stream, the appropriate end-of-line sequence for the system will be written to the file (e.g. `\r\n` for Windows). Does inserting an endline in a `std::stringstream` result in the system-appropriate end-of-line sequence being written to the string? For example:

```
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::endl;
    std::string endlineSequence = oss.str();
    bool isWindows = enlineSequence == "\r\n";
    bool isOldMac  = endlineSequence == "\r";
    bool isUnix    = endlineSequence == "\n";
    // Will this work???
}
```

Comment: To save your time, you can execute and see if all the `bool`s in your program are `true` or not... most likely `isWindows` and `isMac` will evaluate to `false`.

Comment: @Aditya: I'd have to try on each platform. Not everyone has a Windows, Mac, and Unix box at their disposal. :-)

Comment: @Emile: no, you only need to try it in Windows. Because if you write `\n` and get `\r\n`, it does the translation to native newline; and if you get `\n` it doesn't. It's not noticeable in Linux or MacOS X, though.

Comment: on both windows and linux machines,  isUnix evaluates to true.

Comment: @Aditya: Thanks. That validates Björn's answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The system specific line endings are only relevant for text **files**. As long as the stream is only in memory, it is just `'\n'`.

Comment: How can it be anything but the single character '\n' in a string stream? Suppose the translation was done on a string stream. Think of the mess that would result with `sstream1 << "\n"; sstream2 << stream1.str(); ...; std::cout << sstream99.str();`

Comment: Works also for Windows OutputDebugStringA

Answer (score 3):

*Short answer*: **No**.

*Long answer*:

The file stream in text mode will insert a platform specific ELS into the file. But the application will never see this as the ELS is converted back into `\n` when the file is read. So even with file stream (in text mode) you will never see the ELS.

Back to the `std::stringstream`. If the code did insert a platform specific ELS (which it does not) then when you read the stream you would still expect to see `\n` when you read it back as you would expect the ELS to be converted back. There is little point in doing so.