# Unix c++: getline and line.empty not working

Tags: c++, unix, getline

Happy New Year, everyone!

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
A|AAAAA|1|2
R|RAAAA
R|RAAAA

A|BBBBB|1|2
R|RBBBB
R|RBBBB

A|CCCCC|1|2 
R|RCCCC
```

The following code searches for the relevant text in the file based on the key and returns all the lines that belong to the key:

```
while( std::getline( ifs, line ) && line.find(search_string) != 0 );

if( line.find(search_string) != 0 )
{
    navData = "N/A" ;
}

else{

    navData = line + '\n' ; // result initially contains the first line

    // now keep reading line by line till we get an empty line or eof
    while( std::getline( ifs, line ) && !line.empty() )
    {
        navData += line + '\n';
    }
}

ifs.close();
return navData;
```

In Windows I get what I need:

```
A|BBBBB|1|2
R|RBBBB
R|RBBBB
```

In Mac, however, code "&& !line.empty()" seems to get ignored, since I get the following:

```
A|BBBBB|1|2
R|RBBBB
R|RBBBB

A|CCCCC|1|2
R|RCCCC
```

Does anyone know why?

Cheers, everyone!

Comment: Is the `;` after the first `while` intentional?

Comment: Yes. Works this way. Cheers,

Comment: `{}` would be clearer. I missed the `;` originally and wondered why you were repeating the `.find` condition in a strange place :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows and Mac have different opinions about how an empty line looks like. On Windows, lines are teminated by `"\r\n"`. On Mac, lines are terminated by `"\n"` and the preceding `"\r"` leads to the line not being empty.

Comment: For reference, this is one big reason there's an `ios_base::binary` flag.  With an output stream in binary mode, what you write is what gets written; in text mode (the default), line endings may be translated so that (for example) `\n` becomes `\r\n`.  *nix typically doesn't treat the two differently, but Windows typically will.  (Your text editor will often let you specify the line terminator as well, for similar reasons.)

Comment: OK. So how should I solve my problem with that taken into consideration? Thanks!

Comment: So you want to be [using `getline()` with multiple types of end of line characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995971/using-get-line-with-multiple-types-of-end-of-line-characters)? I'm sure that now that you know where the problem is, you will find a solution.

Comment: Oswald, Thanks a lot! The function safeGetline found in one of your links did the trick! Much appreciated!